# Use CSS or jQuery to expand container horizontally ONLY enough to prevent vertical overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, expand

Alright, so here's what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#test {
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Now, let's imagine that the paragraph in the HTML above can be of variable length. Or maybe there are two paragraphs. It doesn't really matter. What I'm looking for is a CSS or jQuery way to have the `div` always remain 100 pixels tall, and to end up no less than 100 pixels wide, **but** no wider than is necessary to prevent vertical overflow.

So, if the contents are short enough—say, a single word—the `div` will have a height of 100 pixels and a width of 100 pixels. If the contents is an entire paragraph, the `div` will still have a height of 100 pixels, the contents will fill it vertically, and the `div` will expand horizontally **only** enough to prevent overflow.

Comment: So far, I've gotten the following jQuery function, which works, but isn't all that elegant (note that the actual HTML has 10 items I'm doing this for, hence the `each`): `function resize(){
 $("#test").each(function(){
  while (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight) {
   $(this).css({
    'width': '+=50px'
   });
  }
 });
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop to compute the height of the inner paragraph, and continually adjust the width of the parent div until it fits.

```
while ($('#test > p').height() > $('#test').height()) {
    $('#test').width($('#test').width() + 1); // or +5 or +10 for a faster result
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/MFHah/

Warning: this may cause infinite loops in certain circumstances.

Comment: That works. I modified it a bit (I think I'll also check to make sure the `div` doesn't expand beyond its container. http://jsfiddle.net/HmrBX/

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
#test{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. Mayhap I didn't explain clearly enough? Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RC7Vb/) for your solution, and the `div` still expands to 100% of its container, regardless of whether or not its contents are filling the height. Am I missing something?